# Как можно получить текст из элемента по номеру?

Tags: ruby, selenium

Как можно получить текст из элемента по его номеру? Например я получил со страницы count в 10 штук, и из каждого из элемента мне нужно получить значение, как мне это можно сделать в Ruby & selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю Ruby и надеюсь после меня вам напишут ответ напрямую относящийся к вам, мой ответ базируется на знаниях Python 3, и надеюсь что отличия кода будут только синтаксическими).

Так вот, в библиотеке селениума у вас есть функция `find_element_by..` для поиска одного или первого элемента и `find_elements_by..` для поиска всех элементов удовлетворяющих вашему требованию. Выберите любой доступный и удобный способ поиска (по `тексту`, по `xPath` адресу, `css-селектору` и др), и после воспользуйтесь функцией `get_attribute()` указав аргументом функции имя того атрибута, который вам нужен.
Пример для Python 3:

```
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/div[2]/a')
name_title = name.get_attribute('title')
```

В случае если данные содержатся в текстовом поле элемента, вместо `.get_attribute('title')` используется `.text`

```
name_title = name.text
```

Так же, если использовать стороннюю библиотеку парсинга, а не селениум (в Python 3 таковыми являются `lxml`, `beautiful soup` и др.). То можно прямо обращаться к данным в элементе (по крайне мере так можно в `lxml`, а вот на счёт других не уверен). Выглядит это так:

```
tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)  # Парсером.обрабатываем(код_открытой_страницы)
name_text = tree.xpath('//tbody/div[2]/a/text()')  # в_коде_страницы.ищем_элемент(по_указанному_xPath_адресу)
```

Я надеюсь вы сможете адаптировать этот код под Ruby.

Comment: Все в порядке, спасибо, помогло!)